# Recursion sequence - generic approach

Tags: python, recursion

We have the below classic recursion example for Fibonacci numbers

```
def fib(n):
    assert type(n) == int & n >= 0
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) 

fib(5) #=> 8
```

When we call fib(5), when the code is executed is there a sequence in which the fib(n-1) and fib(n-2) in the last line of fib() fcn would be executed  - ie. to ask would the fib(n-1) part be first called, awaited the return and then the fib(n-2) part or they occur in parallel ?

Comment: They will be evaluated sequentially in the order in which they are written.

Answer (score 2):

No, both computations will occur sequentially, and yes, this is a very wasteful way to compute Fibonacci series.

A less wasteful recursive function returns *two* consecutive numbers (current and previous):

```
def fib2(n):
  if n == 1:
    return (0, 1)
  else:
    prev_1, prev_2 = fib2(n-1)
    return (prev_1 + prev_2, prev_1)

def fib(n):
    value, _ = fib2(n)
    return value
```

An even better method [uses matrix exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The fib(n-1) part would be first computed and then the fib(n-2) part.